# log4net string match filter

Tags: c#, log4net

I want to log only my explicit set messages. I set this messages like `log.Info("My message -  User is logged in");` So I was thinking to use stringmatch filter as filter type inside log4net configuration like this

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
  <stringToMatch value="My message - " />
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
```

But inside logfile there are still many messages (mappings, etc.) so aparently I do something wrong here. Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would not do this by filter, but by listen to the specific logger. To get messages specific from your login class, you need to set a specific name to that logger:

```
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MyLoginClass"); //typeof(LoginClass).Name
```

In your config add config for the specific login class logger:

```
<logger name="MyLoginClass">
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="MyAppender"/>
</logger>
```